# Rerun part of code on function value change

Tags: python, tkinter, nested-loops, getter, setter

I'm currently trying to create program that allows a user to view pictures of a shirt the user selects combined with different pants.

The program contains a directory filled with pictures of shirts, aswell as one of pants.
The user selects a shirt from a DropDown-menu, and the program then generates, saves, and displays the all possible combinations created using the shirt.
To accomplish this I'm using Tkinter & PIL (Pillow).

***Here's my problem:*** *When the user edits the DropDown-menu, and selects another shirt, I want the program to generate new images using THAT shirt, and replace the old images currently displayed.*

I've read answers to similar questions, and some suggest a *setter* and *getter*, to detect and call a function when a variables' value is changed. I'm not quite sure I understand how it works, and definetly not how to implement it into my code. The function I want to call is inside a nested loop. Does that make any difference in this context?

Here is the code. The `generateImage()`function is a placeholder for the many rows of code that acutally generate the images.

To detect when the selected option from the DropDown-menu is changed, I use `variable.trace`.

```
shirtcolors = ["blue", "red", "green"]

def ChosenImage(*args):
        chosen_image = variable.get()
        print("value is: " + chosen_image)
        selectedimage = ""

        if chosen_image == "blue":
            selectedimage = "C:/User/Desktop/OutfitGenerator/shirts/IMG_0840.jpg"
        elif chosen_image == "red": 
            selectedimage = "C:/User/Desktop/OutfitGenerator/shirts/IMG_0850.jpg"
        elif chosen_image == "green":
            selectedimage = "C:/User/Desktop/OutfitGenerator/shirts/IMG_0860.jpg"

            return selectedimage

DropdownList = tk.OptionMenu(frame, variable, *shirtcolors)
DropdownList.pack()

variable.trace("w", callback=ChosenImage)

shirtslist = [ChosenImage()]
pantsdirectory= "C:/User/Desktop/OutfitGenerator/pants"
pantslist = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pantsdirecotry, h)) for h in os.listdir(pantsdirecotry)]

for i in shirtslist:
    for j in pantslist:
        def generateImage(file1, file2):
```

My problem is that i can't figure out how to make the program run the code below the `variable.trace` line again. When a callback is sent to `ChosenImage` I want it to also continue the rest of the code, now using the new `selectedimage` value. However the continuation of the code cannot happen until the callback has reached the `ChosenImage` function, and it has changed its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that i can't figure out how to make the program run the
> code below the variable.trace line again. When a callback is sent to
> ChosenImage I want it to also continue the rest of the code, now using
> the new selectedimage value.

This is the wrong way of thinking. Your callback **is** the thing that should generate the combinations/images - your callback shouldn't return anything, it should only have side-effects:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Window")
        self.geometry("256x64")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.shirt_colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]
        self.pants_colors = ["brown", "black"]

        self.drop_down_var = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.drop_down_var, *self.shirt_colors)
        self.menu.pack()

        self.drop_down_var.trace("w", callback=self.on_change)

    def on_change(self, *args):
        # Everytime the selection changes, generate combinations
        shirt_color = self.drop_down_var.get()
        for pant_color in self.pants_colors:
            print("{} shirt with {} pants".format(shirt_color, pant_color))


def main():
    Application().mainloop()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```